# How to send Fax using Asp.net webapplication

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to send fax through my web application.
after grooming all sites, i found that so many similar questions.
but still I'm confused.

My requirement is.. i want to send FAX with attachment using outlook, similar like sending an email with attachment using SMTP (by clicking on button).

I think by using SMTP we not able to send FAX.
Could you please suggest me, Can we send FAX using any open source API?
Anyone have experience with this?

please share sample code in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: SMTP is to send email...

Answer (score 1):

You can send faxes via API using a service like [InterFax](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev), they have libraries for ASP.net as well as either SOAP or REST APIs. It appears to be free.